# Samsung 3.8 v battery + adafruit usb boost

Tags: power-supply, battery

I have a 3.8v / 3100mAh battery from a galaxy note 3. Can I use this along with  https://makersify.com/products/adafruit-powerboost-500-charger-rechargeable-5v-lipo-usb-boost-500ma?

The powerboost says 3.7v, so a bit unsure since the battery is 3.8[image: battery]

Comment: I've used a 4400mAh along with an AdaFruit PowerBoost 1000C to power a Raspberry Pi 3 for 24+ hours (idle, no WiFi/BlueTooth).

Comment: How many volts?

Comment: [Its this battery pack from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/products/354)

Comment: That is pretty impressive @RonBeyer -- an average of 135 mA per hour!  I presume the Pi was shutdown during much of that time, because a 3 will not actually *run* on 3250 mAh (4400 * 3.7 = 16280 mWh / 5 = 3250 mAh @ 5V) for 24 hours if it is doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you can, but due to the voltage curve over power dispassion when your say 20% into the battery it won't be 3.7 or 3.8 volts it's likely to be 3.5 which is too low to run the Pi, at which point the Pi will shut down. Furthermore the Pi needs more than the 500ma that the power boost offers and may have stability issues, depending which Pi you have. You may read more about Pi power requirements [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/)

Comment: I thought the power boost would solve that potential issue? Or will it still be a problem?

Comment: It would still be a problem because your battery voltage will decrease as capacity goes down

Comment: Fair enough - any batteries you can suggest that would do the trick?

Comment: I personally recommend using mobile batteries with high powered ports designed to power tablets such as the morphie x8 which can be found http://www.mophie.com/shop/universal-batteries is the battery bank I use to run my Pi during school projects. But any high quality battery bank that is designed to charge tablets should do

Comment: I'll look at it. I need something small though (plan to build a retropie-infused zero into an old gameboy case)

Comment: @yusijs you could always try running it off aa batteries such as: http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/02/running-a-raspberry-pi-from-6-aa-batteries/ please mark the answer as correct if it has helped you by clicking the checkmark to the left of it

Comment: I generally dont tag an answer as correct until I've been able to verify its correct (or more people verify it's correct). Mostly for people who might find this question later who might go off of wrong info

Comment: @yusijs that's fine, I'm patient, I can wait

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

Depends on the Pi and what you have connected.  500mA is a bit on the light side.  It would probably be okay for a headless Pi.

Might give 2 to 3 hours of operation on a full charge.

Must be cheaper ways of powering the Pi.

Comment: Its a pi zero, and I'd need a display on it (2.4" tft). The products page says this:

Comment: 2A internal switch (~2.5A peak limiting) means you can get 500mA+ from a 3.7V LiPoly/LiIon battery. We had no problem drawing 1000mA, just make sure your battery can handle it

Comment: @yusijs I highly doubt you will be able to draw over 1 amp (because 5v 1amp needs more amps at 3.8v) from a phone battery. The discharge rate would likely kill it

Comment: @mohammad ali looking at e.g https://www.adafruit.com/products/328, my battery has more capacity than this? 3100 mAh, and the adafruit one has 2500. Altho that has a higher max voltage.. I'll give it a go with a volt meter to see what it can max output when fully charged I guess.

Comment: @yusijs also be sure to look up max draw rates for the batteries and factor in the screen when caculator got battery life, a 2.5 ah battery might get you hour maybe hour and a half. Also please read the comments on my answer above